# Crossing variables over 2 pages with php sessions

Tags: php, variables, session

i am new to php and learning to use sessions.

I am trying to cross 2 variables from page1 which are user inputs, to page2 to use in an sql query.

Page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_SESSION['Year'] = $_POST['Year'];
$_SESSION['Term'] = $_POST['Term'];
}
include("includes/header.html");
include("includes/navbar.html");

echo "Year = " . $_SESSION['Year'];
echo "Term = " . $_SESSION['Term'];
?>

<div class="main body"> 

<center>
<form action="view_year.php" method="post">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>What Year would you like to view?:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Year" value="YYYY e.g. 2014"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>What Term would you like to view?:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Term" value="Term1 OR Term2 OR Term3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>

</div>
```

Page2:

```
<?php
session_start();
$year = $_SESSION['Year'];
include("includes/header.html");
include("includes/navbar.html");

echo " The year is " . $year;
?>
```

On page1, the setting of the session variables works and it echos Year = whatever the user inputted, but when using it again on the second page it doesn't.

Am I missing something utterly simple :P?

Thanks guys!

Comment: try to echo the year value before the includes.Or Just check with this print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: have you got any error/warning?

Comment: You don't have to start your session on each page. Calling session_start() a second time in a request doesn't do anything unless the existing session was destroyed

Comment: I tired echo before the includes, and after, tried print_r($_SESSION),  nothing is working. I am not getting any errors it literally comes out as The Year is and nothing else (where when im on my first page it comes out as Year = 2014 (2014 being what i put in the form). @castt does it cause any errors keeping them? I tried using it with/without but nothing changed.

Comment: I re-added session_start() on second page, and print_r($_SESSION) worked, but it only produced Array ( [Year] => [Term] => ) So this means the variables from page1 aren't being transferred to page2?

Comment: I am changing pages by form - see edit above for full code on page1 - is it because of that, that the variables aren't being reproduced on page2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are overriding the `$_SESSION['Year']` when you're not checking if the `$_POST`-var is actually sent.

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['Year'])){
    $_SESSION['Year'] = $_POST['Year'];
    $_SESSION['Term'] = $_POST['Term'];
}
```

Comment: This worked and it transferred the variables. But now, I can't override the variables for a new submission. Say I want to set Year = 2012 instead of 2014, going back to page 1 entering 2012 into the form and pressing submit, it still keeps 2014 not the new 2012. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry this doesn't actually work. I renamed my form to stay on page1 where it saved the variables, then because the variables were saved it worked on page2. But going straight from page1 to page2 through the form it doesn't transfer/save the variables.

Comment: This is correct. I put this on the wrong page though. Needs to be put on page2, not page1! Thank you :)